# How to restore Text after changes have been cancelled?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a Label that is bound to a field on my VM.  The Label has two control templates, one for Read-Only and one for an Edit Mode.  Everything works but I have one problem.  If you put the control in Edit-Mode and begin to type in the TextBox and then hit Cancel it doesn't restore it to the original text.  How do I force it to rebind and restore the text to what was on the VM?

```
<Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="ShiftManagerMessages" Content="{Binding Path=Messages, IsAsync=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" Foreground="White" FontSize="18px" Margin="5,5,5,5" 
                                   conv:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.Enabled="False" conv:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.DoLock="{Binding Path=MessageUpdateSuccessful, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="54" Width="1150">
                                <Control.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                        <WrapPanel>
                                            <TextBox Width="1000" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Property=HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" AllowDrop="True" />
                                    <Button Content="Cancel" Width="65"  Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Cursor="Hand" Margin="5,0,5,0" Click="CancelShiftMessage_Click"  />
                                    <Button Content="Save" Width="50"  Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Command="{Binding SaveMessagesCommand}" />
                                        </WrapPanel>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Control.Template>
                                <conv:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.LockTemplate>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                                        <TextBlock Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay }" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                                   Foreground="{TemplateBinding Property=Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding Property=FontSize}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Property=HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Property=VerticalAlignment}" /> 
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </conv:ReadOnlyControlTemplate.LockTemplate>
                            </Label>
```

I have tried the a few variations of the only binding update that I know of but they were not successful.

```
private void CancelShiftMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadOnlyControlTemplate.SetDoLock(ShiftManagerMessages, true);

        BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(ShiftManagerMessages, Label.ContentProperty).UpdateTarget();
        BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(ShiftManagerMessages, Label.ContentProperty).UpdateTarget();

    }
```

Comment: You need to implement `IEditableObject` interface in your `VM` and call `CancelEdit`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was as Sriram Sakthivel's comment suggested, to Implement the IEditableObject Interface on my ViewModel.  The interface exposes 3 Methods:  BeginEdit(), CancelEdit(), and EndEdit().  I added 3 Commands to coincide with these methods and one bit to indicate whether the mode was readonly or not.

In BeginEdit() I set the editing mode to true and make a copy of the original message.  However if I was dealing with more than one field I would recommend getting a copy of your object using MemberwiseClone.  However if your editing includes any reference types you will want to make a Deep Copy instead.

```
public void BeginEdit()
    {
        IsEditing = true;
        originalmessage = this.Messages;
    }
```

In CancelEdit() I set the message back tot he original and change the edit mode.

```
public void CancelEdit()
    {
        this.Messages = originalmessage;
        IsEditing = false;
    }
```

In EndEdit() I Save the actual changes and reset the edit mode.

```
public void EndEdit()
    {
        IsEditing = false;
        repository.SaveMessages(this.Messages); 
    }
```

In Xaml the control template displayed is bound to the IsEditing Property and the Edit, Cancel, and Save Commands are bound to those created to support IEditableObject.